# AngularJS: change the ng-if value of a specific ng-repeat item?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and javascript for the most part, so this may be a general javascript question:

I have a list of divs created through ng-repeat and each div contains an ng-if="expanded == true" that is made true by clicking a button and running the below function.

How do I change the ng-if value to true for only that specific ng-if inside that div? The current set up changes expanded to equal true and *all* of the ng-if material then shows.

```
//HTML

    <div class="panel-body">
        <span ng-if="expanded == false">This property is missing several documents. Click <a ng-click="buyChecklist()">here</a> to complete this profile.</span>
    </div>  

    <ul class="list-group" ng-if="expanded == true">
        <li class="list-group-item text-right" ng-repeat="reqs in buyReqs">
            <span class="pull-left">{{reqs.name}}</span>
            <span><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="">Upload</a></span>
        </li>
    </ul>

//Controller.js 

    $scope.buyChecklist = function() {
        $scope.expanded = true; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change an expanded property for a particular div, this is an indication that you actually need an expanded state per div and not just a single expanded state. So you need an array instead:

```
expanded = [false, false, false, false]; //one per div
```

Then in your html template, you check the expanded index of the particular div using the current index of the ng-repeat loop:

```
<span ng-if="expanded[$index]"> .. </span>
```

Notice the use of the `$index` value. This variable is available to you within a ng-repeat loop.

The [documentation of ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) mentions this and other variables available to you within the loop (i.e. $first, $last, $even, $odd, etc.)

Comment: This may work for a fixed amount of divs, but what if the ng-repeat is based on a dynamic database? The ng-repeat array will vary

Comment: when use expanded[$index] == true or expanded != true, undefined != true too.